# Redirect to https automatically

Tags: ssl, redirect, https, tcp, ssl-certificate

I'm listening on to port 80 and 443 using the TCPListener in my .net application. This is windows service and not a web application therefore not hosted in the IIS as well.

I know there are many ways to redirect the request from http to https using the URL Rewrite in the IIS.

BUT, it there any clean way of redirecting all the incoming requests on port 80 to port 443. Basically I want to enforce a secure connection with the server. 
Any help in this regard will be great.

Thanks

Comment: Either I don't really understand your problem or it really makes no sense. Since you are having a TCPListener on port 80 and 443 and want to do http and https I would expect you to have an understanding of how http (and https) works in the first place, since otherwise you would not be able to implement it in your listener. So you already need to know how to parse a HTTP request and send a HTTP response - and a redirect is just a response with code 302 (or others, depending on what exactly you want to achieve) and a `location` header with the new url.

Comment: I was thinking of some ways of redirection without parsing and responding with the something like 302 code in the HTTP response. But I guess I will have to implement this in the code. Actually the server is deployed and I wanted to resolve this issue with redeployment. That was the background of my question. Thanks for your help.